# Create a vertical line for design using ChakraUI and React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, chakra-ui

I am trying to create a landing page for my website using React and ChakraUI. In my design, I created a few lines so the page looks better and now when implementing it I realized I don't really know what the right approach is. Do I manually make it with boxes and round corners? :)) Please let me know. I have attached a screenshot here with the line for better understanding. Thank you very much for the help!

https://gyazo.com/d85d34d74e692c10f005a195ff1b6ec7

(the line with circle on the left side)